# Searching for string in stdout in python

Tags: python, stdout, paramiko

I have written this code which will get certain output from a server using paramiko module. Now i am struggling to figure out how to search for an output that has greater then zero value and print it.

```
    cmd1 = 'statvv -d 10 -iter 1 ' + (row[2])
    stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh_client.exec_command(cmd1)
    io_check = (stdout.read().decode(encoding='ascii'))
    print(io_check)
```

This is the output i get from above:-

```
16:35:04 03/10/2020 r/w I/O per second KBytes per sec    Svt ms IOSz KB

                  VVname      Cur  Avg  Max  Cur  Avg  Max  Cur  Avg Cur Avg Qlen
DW345T77-shared-NC.160   t    9    8    12   37   38   38 0.03 0.03 4.2 4.2    0
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                      1   t    9    9        38   38      0.03 0.03 4.2 4.2    0

16:35:10 03/10/2020 r/w I/O per second KBytes per sec    Svt ms IOSz KB

                  VVname      Cur  Avg  Max  Cur  Avg  Max  Cur  Avg Cur Avg Qlen
DCAWERB07-shared-NC.120   t    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0   0   0   0
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                      1   t    0    0         0    0      0.00 0.00 0.0 0.0    0
```

There will be hundreds of output like this. I am only interested on printing the output whose 'Cur' value is greater then zero. The above example is two output from the command in which first one's value is greater then zero ( which i need to print ) ... Second one has 'Cur' as zero so I don't need it.

Comment: Do you only want the line with the non-zero cur . . . or do you want to printout the whole little "sub-report" (that is from the line with datetime, to the line just before the next datetime)?

Comment: wait for the line that contains the headers `VVname Cur Avg`, then read the next line and extract the third word, read one line ignore it, read a line and extract the 3 word and check its value.

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Can you be more specific?

Comment: @FrankMerrow - I want to print that is from the line with datetime to the line just before next datetime that contain value greater then zero.

Comment: @AMC - From the output above I just want to print the first output because the 'Cur' value is greater then Zero. I need to print everything starting from first datetime just before next datetime.

Comment: That's still not very specific.

Answer (score 0):

I have no tricky/easy way to do this.

Loop through the input lines doing the obvious:

1. If this is a "datatime" line, decide if you should print out the previous report or not.
2. Then start a new report using the datetime line as the start of the next report
3. As you collect input for the current report, isolate the "cur" line: If cur != 0 set a flag, otherwise assume false.

It's ugly, but anything based on regular expressions or whatever will likely be more fragile than the direct approach.